# Filter and sum different columns in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large numpy array `data` that I wish to filter by one column `[:,8] <= radius` and get the sum of a different column `[:,7]`

So far I have the following which returns an "invalid slice" error.

```
>>> data.slice
(4700, 9)

>>> np.sum(data[np.where(data[:,8] <= 50):,7])
IndexError: invalid slice
```

I'm pretty new to python so really can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any thoughts or explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for the `np.where` call.

```
data = np.random.normal(size=(20, 2))
np.sum(data[data[:,0] < 0, 1])
```

In this example, I want the rows where `data[:,0] < 0` is `True`, and I want column `1`. So just slice with those and take the sum.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Was working myself into a bit of a confusing state there. Didn't realise I could filter in that way. Much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, after some testing, this doesn't seem to work. `data[data[:,8] <= radius, 7]` doesn't return an array of values from column 7, but instead just a single value.