# Filter numpy array by two conditions. More than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which I need to filter and perform a sum on. Similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289292/filter-and-sum-different-columns-in-a-numpy-array), although this one needs to be filtered by two conditions.

Need to return the sum of column `7` where column `0 == ptype` AND column `8 == radius`.

```
np.sum(data[data[:,0] == ptype and data[data[:,8] <= radius],7])
```

I get the following error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

python's `and` looks at the boolean value on either side of the condition.  Because of design decisions in `numpy`, arrays with more than 1 value don't have a boolean value (it raises `ValueError` as you've seen.  The solution is to use the `np.logical_and` function.

```
mask = np.logical_and(data[:, 0] == ptype, data[:, 8] <= radius)
np.sum(data[mask, 7])
```

Note that `&` will work as well in this case as you have arrays of booleans -- However, I don't like to use that one in general as typically (and with numpy as well), `&` means *bitwise and* rather than *logical and*.

Comment: Thanks this one worked for me. Good explanation too. Might just want to fix the `data[data[:, 8]` bit to be `data[:, 8]`

Comment: @JohnZwinck -- Thanks for the edit.  :-)  And the initial refactor code . . .

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `&` instead of `and` with NumPy arrays:

```
mask = (data[:,0] == ptype) & (data[:,8] <= radius)
data[mask,7].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming the easier to read version should be `data[:,8] <= radius` ?

Comment: @Carl: yes, thanks, I fixed that, copied a bug from the question by accident.  :)

Comment: Also get an error: `ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: @JohnZwinck, you need to parenthesize the expressions, bitwise-and, unlike boolean-and, has higher precedence than comparison operators.